# Как в WordPress ввести комментарии задним числом / через базу данных

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

*Внес правки в заголовок и в сам вопрос. Спасибо @SeVlad, удалось выйти на нужное решение.*

Небольшой сайт был переведен на Wordpress с голого HTML. Предусмотрена отдельная страница для обратной связи с комментариями. В сайт на голом HTML комментарии посетителей записывались вручную копипастой из электронной почты (формы не было, сайт был статический). Комментарии в таком формате сохранились до сих пор, выбрасывать их нежелательно.

Теперь любой комментарий, который удобно было бы просто "одобрить" в консоли WP, приходится опять копипастить, а затем удалять, иначе становится видно, где старые комментарии, а где - добавленные через форму, это выглядит очень грубо. Как добавить все старые комментарии, будто их тоже через форму вводили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением стал phpMyAdmin:

1. Скачал phpMyAdmin версии 4, т.к. у меня PHP 5.2
2. Добавил три тестовых комментария, чтобы в базе был образец
3. Открыл на редактирование файл wp-config.php
4. Забрал оттуда логин и пароль от MySQL
5. Открыл phpMyAdmin, залогинился
6. Нашел таблицу wp-comments
7. Методом "Copy" копировал шаблон комментария и заполнял базу
8. Нашел скрипт comments-fix вот [здесь](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-category-and-comment-count-after-wordpress-import/)
9. С его помощью исправил отображаемое количество комментариев (WP по-прежнему писал, что их 3, когда их было уже 70, потому что они были внесены в базу вручную).
10. Вышел и удалил phpMyAdmin в целях безопасности.

Answer (score 1):

> Как добавить все старые комментарии, будто их тоже через форму
>   вводили?

На этой странице "обратной связи" убрать отдельную форму и разрешить комментарии.

Comment: Спасибо! Но именно  в таком случае текст получается неоднородным. Все старые данные сделаны простым текстом, это, по сути, не комментарии, а тело страницы. Новые комментарии Wordpress добавляет в другом стиле. Получается "колхоз". Мне нужно простой старый текст разбить на соответствующие кусочки и преобразовать до комментариев. Есть ли способ?

Comment: Ну перенести старые комменты в коменты. Или же использовать плагины типа вопрос-ответ, но тоже в них нужно как-то импортировать старое.

Comment: Или использовать плагины обратной связи с возможностью записи в БД (для CF7 тоже есть разные дополнения). Но тут уже наверное не одна страница будет.